# Pecked to Death By Keychains

Tags: macos, keychain

Every time I close the lid on my MacBook Pro, running 10.6.2, and open it again, Mail, Cal, and/or Adium will pop up the keychain unlock dialog. Even if they are minimized to the task bar. The unlock dialog squats there, modally, until I oblige it with a password.

Does anyone know how to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make a backup of `login.keychain`:

```
cp ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain ~/login.keychain.bak
```

Then delete it:

```
rm ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

the reason to keep a backup is in case you want to restore your saved passwords. This will stop the prompts however.

Comment: That has rather dramatic consequences. I think you should edit your answer to warn people about the loss of all their saved passwords, and then I'll accept it.

Comment: create a backup of your keychain :)

Answer (score 3):

This is often because the keychain security level has been set too high...

Go into Keychain Access (Utilities --> Keychain Access)...

1) Keychain Access Menu --> Keychain First Aid --> Authenticate, Choose Repair Keychain --> Start

2) Edit Menu --> Keychain Settings
    * Update the "Lock After XX Minutes of inactivity" to whatever settings you want
    * Most likely, you will want to turn off "Lock when sleeping".

Comment: settings were already as you recommend here.

Comment: Than chances are that the keychain password is *DIFFERENT* than your computer's login password.  You can either recreate your keychain (John T's answer), or reset the keychain password to match.

Answer (score 0):

At least on Mac OS X through 10.5.x, this is NOT the default behavior.

However, if you are using SSHKeychain or a third-party tool, this may lock the login keychain when the laptop goes to sleep.

Comment: no such tools installed. Also, I do have 'require password when awake from sleep'. I don't mind the initial prompt to unlock the keychain, it's the individual app prompts that do the pecking.